# Examples of varieties whose canonical bundle is relatively globally generated w.r.t. the Albanese morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of smooth complex projective varieties. A line bundle $L$ on $X$ is said to be $f$-relatively globally generated if the natural morphism
$$f^* f_* L \rightarrow L$$
is surjective.

Let now $\omega_X$ be the canonical line bundle of $X$, and $alb_X : X \rightarrow \mathrm{Alb} X$ its Albanese morphism.
I'm interested in the case when $\omega_X$ is $alb_X$-relatively globally generated.
For instance, curves of positive genus and, more generally, varieties with finite Albanese morphism have this property.

I'm looking for some other non-trivial examples. Thanks in advance!